# Factor Analysis - restricting Loadings

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, linear-algebra

I´m new to Multivariable Statistics and just started to learn about Factor Analysis.

I do understand that for p=k (there are as many factors as dimensions in the data) L (loadings) is unique. 
But for k

To find a unique representation of L, I found the following restriction in my study materials:

$$L^{t}V^{-1}L = Δ $$

where $\Delta= $ any diagonal matrix and
$V=E(\epsilon\epsilon^{t})=diag(v_1^{2}, v_2^{2}, ...,v_p^{2})$  when $x=Lf+\epsilon$

this restriction apparently implies that:

$$ L = V^{1/2} U V^{1/2}$$
$$ V^{-1/2}(\Sigma-V)V^{-1/2}=U\Delta U ^{t}$$

I guess my mathematics is not strong enough, but I seem to not get what is going on here, and I don't have any intuition, about what we are doing.

my thoughts so far.
 $\Sigma$ is a p.d and symmetric matrix, and so is $\Sigma-V$, I tried to write the last equation as $V^{-1/2}\Sigma V^{-1/2} - I = U\Delta U^{t}$ but that doesn't seem to be any better, and so I am clueless.

Many Thanks!
l